# Mocking onSubmit on react-final-form using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocking, react-testing-library, react-final-form

I have a form built using `react-final-form`, `yup`, and `Material-ui`. I am testing using `Jest`, and `@testing-library/react`.

### TL;DR:

- Is there a way to mock and test only the `onSubmit` function while bypassing/ leveraging the `validate` functionality?
- Is there a better way to go about it?

---

The mocked `onSubmit` function was not called because I leveraged `RFF`'s `validate` function. It seems the `validate` function is hanging during the submit process. Besides mocking the `validate` function, is there a *best practice* in building the validator function so the tests recognize that the mocked `onSubmit` has been called?

When I try to test whether the form has been submitted it seems to hang on the validate method.

```js
fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('test-form')) // or
fireEvent.click(getByTestId('submit-button'))
```

[image: mocking function failure]

#### The mocked onSubmit function is not recognized and seems to hang on the `validate` method.

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    code: yup
        .string()
        .trim()
        .required('Please provide a Code')
        .max(32, 'The Code is too long')
})

const validate = values =>
    schema
        .validate(values, { abortEarly: false })
        .then(valid => ({}))
        .catch(err => extractError(err))

<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  validate={validate}
  render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {...fields and submit button here}
    </form>
  )
/>
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-tesla-qozho]

Comment: I'd need to see the code for your entire test, I think. Ideally the smallest version that fails. All of RFF's internal testing is done with `@testing-library/react`, so maybe you can look into that source for some insights?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have been using RFF's internal testing files as a reference point--which makes this feel even more bizarre.

Comment: I identified that the core issue was not mocking the `validate` prop. Is there a *best practice* way to test the full integration of a form without having to mock the validate function? I was looking at [Final-Forms validation testing](https://github.com/final-form/final-form/blob/master/src/FinalForm.validating.test.js) but can't seem to find an example that includes testing the mocked `onSubmit` @ErikR.

Comment: You don't need to provide a `validate` function. Maybe can you show me a more concrete example that's failing? I'm not understanding.

Comment: @ErikR. The codesandbox should have the updated example where the test fails. Ultimately, I would like to test the whole behavior of the form, including the `validate` method and for it to pass. Is there a way to accomplish the whole form passing the test? Or do you recommend to test the behaviors separately?

--also thank you for all your work on `RFF` & `FF` 

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pinpoint the source of the problem. I was leveraging the `validate` prop without mocking it in my tests. I solved this issue by mocking/ testing the `validate` function separately. Big thanks to @ErikR for the assistance